# Result of Long Positive Integers & Search and element in array

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, programming-languages

I have two Questions for which I cannot find answers by googling, but I find these questions very important for preparation.. Kindly explain only the logic, I will be able to code.

In Search of Efficient Logic..... in terms of Memory and Time.

1. WAP to add two long positive integers. What Data structure / data type we can use to store the numbers and result.
2. What is the best way to search an element from an array in shortest time. Size of the array could be large enough, and any elements could be stored in the array(i.e. no range).

Thanks.

Comment: This question makes little sense. Are you really asking what data structure to use to store the result of an integer addition? And what do you mean by "size of the array could be large enough"? Does this array contain integers?

Comment: Yes what data structure to use, to store the numbers and the result.... Linked List or Array.... Any article related to this topic.....

By size of array i mean, the no. of elements the array can store, can be large enough...

Answer (score 1):

A simple array is fine for storing long numbers, then the logic for addition follows naturally.

3 byte arrays would work well, two for the numbers to be added and one for the result.

The fastest way to search an element in an array would be some sort of [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), so long as the array is sorted

Comment: No... array is not sorted...... we need some other algo to search the element in shortest time.. we can use some memory if required....

Comment: If the array isn't sorted then you're stuck. You'll have to iterate through the array until you find find the element you want. That'll be quicker than trying to sort the array first - unless of course you need to find lots of elements within the same array

Answer (score 0):

1. Since it`s mentioned the numbers are large enough a linked list where each node is based on the indices of the digits within a number. A traversal through a single list can help us with the solution.
2. If it`s sorted then Binary search would be apt , but if not Hash table would be the best pick as it takes constant time.